# Como executar programa em python ao iniciar linux mint

Tags: linux

Fiz um programa em python e gostaria de inicia-lo junto ao sistema, mas não sei como.
já tentei o cron @reboot, mas não tive sucesso.

Não sei bem como funciona o ~/.bashrc
fiz assim.

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

dentro dele coloquei.

```
alias opentray='python /usr/share/trayMenuCode/trayMenuCode.py'
```

sem sucesso.
talvez isso nem faça sentido.

```
img
    imagens.png
    ....
tray.db
trayMenuCode.py
```

alguém poderia dar uma luz.

Comment: O `.bashrc` só é executado quando vc inicia uma sessão do bash com o seu usuário (e se abrir várias sessões, ele executa várias vezes, uma pra cada sessão), e o `alias` só serve para criar um atalho (um comando mais curto, pra vc não ter que digitar o comando mais longo). Talvez o que queira seja isso: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56957

Answer (score 3):

**Olá, amigo, bom dia.**

Cara, no bashrc você vai alterar apenas a rotina quando abrir o terminal.

**Passo 1**:

```
Crie seu arquivo .py onde quiser, exemplo: "/home/meuscript.py"
```

---

**Passo 2**:
Crie um arquivo com nome:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/meuscript.service
```

ou

```
sudo touch /lib/systemd/system/meuscript.service
```

> OBS: Tanto faz a forma com que você crie o arquivo, mas distros
>   baseadas em Ubuntu/Debian vão utilizar como padrão o nano, mas caso
>   não tenham ou seja outro tipo de distribuição, utilize o touch mesmo.

---

Passo 3:
Após criar o arquivo seguindo o passo 2, copie e cole o código abaixo no arquivo que você criou

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/meuscript.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> OBS: em ExecStart=/usr/bin/python **/home/meuscript.py** você altera
>   pelo caminho de onde você criou seu script em python.
>
> OBS 2: E em "**My Script Service**" você altera para o nome do serviço que quer que seu script se chame.
>
> OBS 3: "ExecStart" é o comando que o sistema vai startar ao ligar, mas caso você queira adicionar mais algum parâmetro após o nome do script, ai é com você mesmo.

Se você quiser armazenar a saída de log do script em um arquivo, pode fazer da seguinte forma lá no "**meuscript.service**":

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/meuscript.py > /home/meuscript.log 2>&1
```

> OBS: pode salvar os logs em **/var/logs** também.

---

**Passo 4**:
Dê permissão ao arquivo:

```
sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/meuscript.service
```

---

**Passo 5**:
Habilite o arquivo como serviço no systemd:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl enable meuscript.service
```

Espero que ajude, cara. 
Grande abraço.